# Adding await to RenderPartialView produces an error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

This is an ASP.net core web application view.  This works:

```
        @if (r.Identifier.HasAcronym)
        {
            @Html.RenderPartialAsync("Resources", new Tuple<IEnumerable<FileSystemObject>, string>(r.ResourcesByAcronym, r.Identifier.Acronym));
        }
```

this produces the error: *Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object'*

```
        @if (r.Identifier.HasAcronym)
        {
            @await Html.RenderPartialAsync("Resources", new Tuple<IEnumerable<FileSystemObject>, string>(r.ResourcesByAcronym, r.Identifier.Acronym));
        }
```

Comment: Best practice when using HTML helper, is to use PartialAsync:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-5.0. But I will recommend you to use tag helpers when developing new stuff:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/partial-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write like this：

```
<td>
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("Resources", new Tuple......);
    }
</td>
```

Html.RenderPartialAsync returns a Task, so the result type is void. The @ without braces asks Razor to render the result, which is not possible: There is no way to convert void to anything renderable. This would only be the right way to go if Html.RenderPartialAsync returned a string, which needed to be rendered manually. The braces introduce a new code block, which allows standard C# syntax.